# If $gng^{-1} = m$ then is it true that $g^2ng^{-2}=m^2?$

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $gng^{-1} = m$ then is it true that $g^2ng^{-2}=m^2?$ for all $g,n,m \in G$ where $
G$ is a group

Comment: -1 What are $g$, $m$ and $n$? Are these elements of a group? And what are your thoughts on the problem?

Comment: $m^2 = m\times m = (gng^{-1})\times (gng^{-1}) = gn(g^{-1}g)ng^{-1}=\dots$

Comment: $m^2 = g^2ng^{-2} \iff gn^2g^{-1} = g^2ng^{-2} \iff n^2g = gn$ Not necessarily. Take $n = 2$ and $g = 1$ with group of real numbers without zero with multiplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to see whether
$$
(gng^{-1})^2=g^2ng^{-2}\tag{*}
$$
Expanding the left-hand side we find $gng^{-1}gng^{-1}=gn^2g^{-1}$, so the equality (*) becomes $gn^2g^{-1}=g^2ng^{-2}$; removing alike terms from the left and from the right, we get
$$
n^2=gng^{-1}
$$
that's generally false.

Take $G=S_3$, $n=(12)$ and $g=(123)$; then $n^2$ is the identity, whereas
$$
gng^{-1}=(123)(12)(132)=(23)\ne n^2
$$

Comment: Thanks egreg....I got it..

Comment: Probably a simpler counterexample can be found taking any abelian group, so that $n^2=gng^{-1}$ simplifies to $n^2=n$, thus $n=1$.

Comment: @lisyarus Of course; I just wanted to use a more concrete example.

Answer (score 2):

This question needs more clarification, but my guess is that the answer is false.
You do not need to look further than the group of rationals (without 0) with multiplication as the operator.

$n = m = 3,
g = 2$

Then $gn = mg$ but the second relation does not hold.

Comment: Nice xplanation ndn. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Conjugation by $g$ defines an *inner automorphism* of $G$.

Thus $i_g(n)=gng^{-1}$ has the same order as $n$.

In general,  $n^2$ and $n$ do not have the same order.

But your claim implies $i_g(n)=n^2$ (easy to see). This is not possible when $2\mid\mid n\mid$.